# sin x integral qestions

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How could the following integral be solved in a good manner?

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x$$

Regards:

Comment: This is three elementary integrals in an hour.  Is there some reason you are unable to do your own work?

Comment: This doesn't have an elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: No just for learning i have three problem that mentioned all

Comment: @T.Bongers:  True.  Perhaps "three integrals with elementary integrands."  But that's a mouthful that doesn't justify the circumlocution.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163305/what-is-the-integral-of-function-fx-sin-x-x

Comment: This is the definition of function $Si(x)$ (the sine integral)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  Almost.  Up to a "$+C$" since $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ is the incomplete integral starting at zero.  But this is a triviality...

Comment: @EricTowers. Perfectly correct ! Thanks for precising. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, $sin(x)/x$ is harder to tackle, thus, we can only approximate. We have to rely on [sin(x)'s power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series),

$$\frac {\sin(x)}{x} \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!}$$

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx \approx \int1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} dx$$

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3*3!} + \frac{x^5}{5*5!} - \frac{x^7}{7*7!} + 
C$$

Comment: You forgot to divide by $x$ in the power series

Comment: I thought the power series of $\frac {\sin x}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} ..$??

Comment: Its fixed now, sorry about that.